# My code just RANDOMLY DISAPPEARED?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, encoding, windows-phone

My `MainPage.xaml.cs` (code behind) file for my Windows Phone project will no longer open properly. When clicked in Visual Studio it just opens a blank-looking notepad document (yet it still scrolls as if there is something there...?) and does not open in the regular code editor. I can't view my code at all as of right now.

My guess would be some kind of strange encoding error but how do I fix this? This project is an app which is on the market and I CANNOT afford to lose this file.

[image]

Comment: If this change is made by visual studio, you may could use Undo(Ctrl + Z) operation to get back the file.
Don't you have source control system to manage your project?

Comment: No, I do not. Everything is stored on my local computer. I can't undo because this happened when I loaded from a save and there is nothing to undo from.

Comment: Tried a rebuild and the actual event handlers aren't even showing up as being there. WTF?

Comment: Open the source files in notepad (or Emacs or any other text editor you prefer) to see if anything is obviously wrong.

Comment: It's 32 Kilobites of what appear to be spaces.

Comment: _"This project is an **app which is on the market** and **I CANNOT afford to lose this file**."_ - you might have lost your recent changes but at least you can revert to the latest file that resides in your source control system.  You _are_ using source control I hope?

Comment: No, i'm not using source control, which obviously is a stupid decision, but there's clearly not much I can do about that now.

Comment: @Kevin I have an idea what you could try but I'd rather not mention it here so as to protect your intellectual property.  Can I contact you via email or something?

Comment: Sure email me at appfinity@outlook.com